# VS2012 One-Click Windows app using SQL Server Express

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-express

I have developed a windows app using  VS2012 (C#) with a database using SQL Server Express.

I wish to publish it (on a CD) using the new one-click wizard.

The database is not shared - so I want the client system to host its own database using a local SQL Server Express.

What pre-requisites do I set? and how do I ensure that the client system will download and install them?

All my efforts so far have failed - because the client is refused 'permission' or some such transient message which disappears before I can read it!

Maybe I cannot use SQL Server Express in this way.

Thank-you